# Invoking a deployed SCCM package through powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

I've been struggling to figure out a way to invoke a package that's already deployed out to a client in SCCM, using Powershell.

I'm able to run a Application using WMI, but it only works with applications, not packages.

```
 $Application = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CCM_Application -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ComputerName $Computername | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $AppName})

 $Args = @{EnforcePreference = [UINT32] 0
 Id = "$($Application.id)"
 IsMachineTarget = $Application.IsMachineTarget
 IsRebootIfNeeded = $False
 Priority = 'High'
 Revision = "$($Application.Revision)" }

 Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ClassName CCM_Application -ComputerName $Computername -MethodName $Method -Arguments $Args
```

Anyways, using the CCM_Application class, i'm able to list out all of the applications deployed to that workstation, and I can install/uninstall, it just doesn't show any packages. I found the CCM_Program / CCM_ProgramManager class, but it doesn't return any packages/task sequences. Has anyone else been able to achieve this? or is it not possible through Powershell? I found some .dll that someone wrote in C# which seems to work with applications/packages, but I'd like to not load any dependencies if possible.

Comment: What properties does the C# dll target? It may just be a matter of digging through subproperties to find what you're after

Comment: So I assume you are talking about available and not required packages? Or do you want to re-run required packages? In general it is not a good idea to install an available program by script because this is just a very convoluted workaround for making the package required. If it has to be done afaik the method is the one I posted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388276/install-sccm-packages-with-powershell