# Install SCCM packages/Applications via Powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I've made a script that runs in our Client Deployment cycle after our task sequence, where packages and applications are being installed.
However, we noticed that it took a long time to finish, as most programs are in the evalutationState 26 (Download success (downloading during install job)).
I want to force the installation of the programs, that essentially are in this state, so that it doesn't take ages to complete.

I've had a look MS Docs regarding installing ccm applications (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/clients/sdk/install-method-in-class-ccm_application?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and made the following:

```
$applications = get-wmiobject -query "SELECT * FROM CCM_Application" -namespace "ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK" | Select-Object FullName, InstallState, EvaluationState, ErrorCode, Id, Revision, IsMachineTarget
$appID = $applications.ID
$appRevision = $applications.Revision
$appMachineTarget = $applications.IsMachineTarget
try
{
    # Documentation MS Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/clients/sdk/install-method-in-class-ccm_application?redirectedfrom=MSDN
    ([WmiClass]'Root\CCM\ClientSDK:CCM_Application').Install($appID, $appRevision, $appMachineTarget, 0, "Normal", $false) | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Exception]
{
     $errorMessage = $_.Exception
     Write-Log "Failed to start the installation. Reason: $errorMessage"
}
```

However, when logging in the log file, I can see that I catch an exception:

---

[17:04:31]  :  Trying to force installation of Citrix Netscaler Access Gateway 13.0.84.11 en-US

[17:04:31]  :  Failed to start the installation. Reason: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040E14)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)

at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)

at System.Management.Automation.ManagementClassApdapter.InvokeManagementMethod(ManagementObject wmiObject, String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParams)

---

I tried having a look at this post ([Install SCCM packages with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388276/install-sccm-packages-with-powershell)), but the answer:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class CCM_Program -Namespace "root\ccm\clientsdk"
```

doesn't bring up the same applications as CCM_Application

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is happening due to an expected datatype mismatch.
I would move the variable declaration for appID,appRevision,appMchineTarget and the method-call into a foreach statement, since the method may have problems handling an array for every parameter.

Also, the CCM_Program cannot display Applications, because Applications and Programs are different type of "softwarepackages" on the client, as well as on the server. They are handled seperately in WMI. Maybe there are no packages deployed to you machine? For managing package-installation via powershell, you can take a look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/clients/sdk/ccm_programsmanager-client-wmi-class